# Write a file in internal storage specific folder in Android

Tags: android

I want to write a file in internal storage in  a specific folder, I get error when creating fileoutputStream.
Below is my code:

```
String filePath = ctx.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() +"/"+folderName;
Log.d("filePath",filePath);
file= new File(filePath, filename);
final FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Comment: what error did you get? post your stack trace.

Comment: @NabinBhandari IOException err

Comment: post full stack trace. if you are running your app on android verson 6.0 or higher, you need to check for permissions in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can go this way.

```
File directory = new File("path_to_directory");
try {
if(!file.exists()) {
directory.createNewFile();
}
File dataFile = new File(directory, "Your File Name");
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(dataFile, true); // true if append is required.
stream.write();
stream.flush()
}
catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
if (null != stream) {
stream.close();
}
```

Here `path_to_directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.seperator + "FolderName";`

OR

```
path_to_directory = ctx.getFilesDirectory() + File.seperator + "FolderName";
```

By the way, you cannot create a folder into android's internal storage until it is rooted. It will definitely give you the IOException because without root the android internal FS is read-only. So be aware of that.

Thanks,
Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

okay if you want to save it from volley (or download it and save to specific folder) here the code

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            downloadUri);

    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle(notesName)
           // .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/YOUR PATH"+"/"+OTHER PATH, notesName)
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
```